# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Issue on angularjs app

Tags: angularjs

XMLHttpRequest cannot load domain.com/contact-form.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'domain.com:81' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Add this headers into your PHP file before all the code.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

Hope it will solve the issue.

Comment: I am still getting error: 
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at domain.com/contact-form.php. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.config.js (your angular config file)

           $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = 'text/plain';
           $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

config.php (your php config file)
          header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
          header("Content-Type: text; charset=UTF-8");
          header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
          header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
          ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
          error_reporting(1);
```